# How to Read excel CLOB data from DB without writing it to a file locally

Tags: java, excel, character-encoding, clob

Excel file(f1) is stored in DB as CLOB data.Using below Java code am able to Read the excel clob data from DB and writing it to local file.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name, data FROM 
    excelclob where name=? ");
    stmt.setString(1, "Test.xls");
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
    String name = resultSet.getString(1);        
    //writing to local file
     File data = new File("M:\\Test.xls");        
      Reader reader = resultSet.getCharacterStream(2);        
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(data);
      char[] buffer = new char[1];        
      while (reader.read(buffer) > 0) {           
       writer.write(buffer);
      }
      }
```

The local file created with correct data(readable format).But i don't want to create file in locally,want to see the readable data in console before writing it to a file.